# Determine whether a set is Invariant, Positively invariant or negatively invariant

Tags: dynamical-systems, set-invariance

I have just started a dynamical systems course and I am a bit confused as to how to determine if something is positively or negatively invariant, or just invariant.

I know the defintions for invariance are as follows:

Let $B \subset X$.

$B$ is called 
**Positively Invariant** if $S_tB\subset B$ for all $t \geq 0$

B is called **negatively invariant** if $S_tB\supset B$

B is called **invariant** if $S_tB=B$ for all $t\geq 0$

Here are some questions I am stuck on:

Considering the continuous time dynamical system given by the ODE $x'=-x$
with solution $x(t)=xe^{-t}$, determine if the following sets are invariant, positively or negatively invariant.

1.) $M \subset \mathbb R : M=(0,1)$

So, I have that $S_t((0,1))=(0,-e^{-t})\not\subset B=(0,1)$ for all $t>0$

Then, for $t=0$, we have $S_t((0,1))=(0,-1)\not\subset(0,1)$ for all $t=0$.

Hence, I cannot see how this is invariant at all? None of the defintions apply here or have I done it all wrong?

2.) $[-1,1]$

I have that this one is positively invariant as $S_tx=xe^{-t} \in [1,1]$ for all $t \geq 0$ and $x\in[-1,1]$

3.) (1,2)

I have this as invariant.

Any help on these much appreciated. Surprisingly few other examples or resources on this on line.

Answer (score -1):

The solution should be written as $x(t) = x_0 e^{-t}$, where $x_0 = x(0)$. 
$S_t$ is the time evolution operator, so $S_t(x) = x e^{-t}$.
Thus for #1, if $x \in (0,1)$, $S_t(x) = x e^{-t} \in (0, e^{-t}) \subset (0,1)$.

Comment: sorry, on my course we have been told to write $x_0$ as just $x$.

Comment: so, i am assuming this makes it positively invariant?

Comment: also, what about for t=0? surely this is not a subset? Im still confused, any further help much appreciated..

Comment: The $\subset$ should really be $\subseteq$.  $S_0(M) = M$.

Comment: Yes, #1 is positively invariant.